# BB web/wdiget(eclipse) vs BB webworks(eclipse)

Tags: blackberry

may i know what the different in BB web/wdiget(eclipse) and BB webworks(eclipse)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlackBerry WebWorks is the new name for BlackBerry Widgets, so they're the same thing, just different versions.

WebWorks info is here:

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/browserdev/widgetsdk.jsp

All the Widgets stuff redirects there now.